# How To Lock A 3D View From Being Roatated ? (2.8)

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

[image]

What do I need to do to lock my Front and Right 3D views from being rotated?

I am using the quad view (Ctrl + Alt + Q)  in the meantime but I only want to work with front and right views only and the Ctrl + Alt + Q View simply does not allow me to enlarge the views I want to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You can lock a camera's rotation in the Transform tab. Press Ctrl + Alt + Numpad0 to align a camera with a view and then check Lock Camera to View.

[image]