# How to lock the view to the XY, XZ, or YZ plane

Tags: 3d-view, axis

When I'm in top, bottom or side view, I would like to **lock the view to the 2 dimensions** of the viewing plane (XY plane, XZ plane or YZ plane), so that - when working in that view - I don't accidentally turn the view into 3 dimensions. How can this be done?

Comment: Check this one out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144411/35559

Answer (score 3):

There's the *Toggle Quad View* option, which has such functionality.
It splits your viewport into multiple views, that *cannot* be rotated.

*View > Area > Toggle Quad View*
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Q</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Just visited this old answer from a year ago, and realized how it doesn't actually answer the question :)